# Replicate PHP code for each section in an INI file

Tags: php, html

```
<? $config = parse_ini_file('/list.ini', true); ?>
<?echo'<select id="LBox" name="listbox" size="20" style="display:none;">';
    foreach($config[MPR] as $id=>$label){
        switch ($id)
        {
        case ($id==select):
        echo'<option value="0" selected="selected"></option>';
        break;
        case ($id>0 && $id<=10):
        echo'<optgroup label="'.$label.'">';
        break;
        case ($id>10 && $id<=20):
        echo'</optgroup>';
        break;
        default:
        echo'<option value="'.$id.'">'.$label.'</option>';
        }
    }
echo'</select>';?>
```

Above is code that builds a hidden list box and fills its options from an INI file. I would Like to replicate this for each section in my ini, but I am unsure of the best way to do this, other than copy and paste this 8 times with a new $config[x] value. Is there a way to replicate this for each section?

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that does it and takes whatever changes (e.g. $config[x]) as an argument.

Comment: I figured that was the right path, I'm still unsure of the best way to do that though. Basically for each [section] or $config[x] A new instance of this must be written.